# Edit a root node celltext in VirtualTreeView

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I would like to change the cell text of an existing virtual (root) node. I can change the data but I have to refresh the whole TreeView so the GetText get's fired again. Is there an easier way or a possible way to refresh only 1 root node and not the whole tree?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `InvalidateNode` function always force the node to repaint, thus also trigger the `OnGetText` event. You must do something wrong. I'll post you a proof if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the following code I've tried to simulate your node updating event. Here is represented by the button click `Button1Click` event. Here if you click the button, the value in the data record will be increased and the node will be forced to repaint (what will trigger the `OnGetText` event, where you will have this new increased value in that record ready to get). In your real code you need to do something like this:

- find the node you want to update (I found the `TopNode` :-)
- update the data record of that node (the `Count` value is incremented in my case)
- call the `InvalidateNode` for that node (what will trigger the *virtual event chain* of some events, but the `OnGetText` will be among them)

```
type
  PTreeData = ^TTreeData;
  TTreeData = record
    Title: string;
    Count: Integer;
  end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  TreeData: PTreeData;
  TreeNode: PVirtualNode;
begin
  // this is just for memory leaks report
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown := True;
  // initialize data size for our data record
  VirtualTree.NodeDataSize := SizeOf(TTreeData);
  // add one node and store it to the TreeNode variable
  TreeNode := VirtualTree.AddChild(nil);
  // get the pointer to just created node data record
  TreeData := VirtualTree.GetNodeData(TreeNode);
  // and assign some values to that data record
  TreeData.Title := 'Count: ';
  TreeData.Count := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  TreeData: PTreeData;
  TreeNode: PVirtualNode;
begin
  // now I take the the top node just as an example
  TreeNode := VirtualTree.TopNode;
  // get the pointer to its data record
  TreeData := VirtualTree.GetNodeData(TreeNode);
  // increase the value in data record for this node
  TreeData.Count := TreeData.Count + 1;
  // and force the node to repaint, what will except
  // other events trigger also the OnGetText one
  VirtualTree.InvalidateNode(TreeNode);
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualTreeGetText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType;
  var CellText: string);
var
  TreeData: PTreeData;
begin
  // here I'll get the pointer to data of the currently refreshed cell's node
  TreeData := VirtualTree.GetNodeData(Node);
  // and return the caption of the cell
  CellText := TreeData.Title + IntToStr(TreeData.Count);
end;

procedure TForm1.VirtualTreeFreeNode(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  Node: PVirtualNode);
var
  TreeData: PTreeData;
begin
  // this is here because of VT memory leaks, so get the pointer to data
  TreeData := Sender.GetNodeData(Node);
  // and finalize them
  Finalize(TreeData^);
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is change edit the selected node text with edit box text

```
procedure Form1.btnEditTextClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Data: PTreeData;
begin
  Data := VST.GetNodeData(VST.FocusedNode);

  Data.Title := Edit2.Text;
  VST.InvalidateNode(VST.FocusedNode);

end;
```